# Android Studio build NDK {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null} Error 87 => Error 1

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I would like to add a opus library with wrapper from github to my project, but I have some errors when building. Maybe somebody know what's going on.

Attach a build log.

```
   Build command failed.    Error while executing process C:\Users\DOROSHKO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsenz.so}



[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= decode_parameters.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= LP_variable_cutoff.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= tables_NLSF_CB_NB_MB.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= tables_NLSF_CB_WB.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= tables_pitch_lag.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= tables_pulses_per_block.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= control_audio_bandwidth.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= HP_variable_cutoff.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= NLSF_del_dec_quant.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= check_control_input.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= inner_prod_aligned.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= LPC_analysis_filter.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= LPC_inv_pred_gain.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= pitch_est_tables.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= resampler_down2_3.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= resampler_private_AR2.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= resampler_private_down_FIR.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= resampler_private_IIR_FIR.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= resampler_private_up2_HQ.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= stereo_decode_pred.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= stereo_encode_pred.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= stereo_find_predictor.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= stereo_quant_pred.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= apply_sine_window_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= corrMatrix_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= encode_frame_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= find_LPC_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= find_LTP_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= find_pitch_lags_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= find_pred_coefs_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= LPC_analysis_filter_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= LTP_analysis_filter_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= LTP_scale_ctrl_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= noise_shape_analysis_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= process_gains_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= regularize_correlations_FLP.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= residual_energy_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= warped_autocorrelation_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= wrappers_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= autocorrelation_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= burg_modified_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= bwexpander_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= energy_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= inner_product_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= LPC_inv_pred_gain_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= pitch_analysis_core_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= scale_copy_vector_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= scale_vector_FLP.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= arm_silk_map.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= biquad_alt_neon_intr.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= LPC_inv_pred_gain_neon_intr.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= NSQ_del_dec_neon_intr.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= arm_celt_map.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= celt_neon_intr.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= pitch_neon_intr.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= opus_multistream_encoder.c 
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= opus_multistream_decoder.c 
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libsenz.so process_begin: CreateProcess


...

D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsenz.so, ...) failed. make (e=87): �������� ����� �������. make: *** [D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsenz.so] Error 87
```

Also add Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE:= senz

#################### COMPILE OPTIONS #######################

# Uncomment this for fixed-point build
#FIXED_POINT=1

# It is strongly recommended to uncomment one of these
#   VAR_ARRAYS: Use C99 variable-length arrays for stack allocation
#   USE_ALLOCA: Use alloca() for stack allocation
#   If none is defined, then the fallback is a non-threadsafe global array
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DUSE_ALLOCA
#CFLAGS := -DVAR_ARRAYS $(CFLAGS)

# These options affect performance
#   HAVE_LRINTF: Use C99 intrinsics to speed up float-to-int conversion
#   inline: Don't use the 'inline' keyword (for ANSI C compilers)
#   restrict: Don't use the 'restrict' keyword (for pre-C99 compilers)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_LRINTF
#CFLAGS := -Dinline= $(CFLAGS)
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Drestrict= $(CFLAGS)

OPUS_VERSION := "1.0.3"
PACKAGE_VERSION := $(OPUS_VERSION)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPUS_VERSION='$(OPUS_VERSION)'
WARNINGS := -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wnested-externs -Wshadow
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O2 -g $(WARNINGS) -DOPUS_BUILD

# TODO: add libNE10 for ARM

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPUS_ARM_ASM -DOPUS_ARM_INLINE_EDSP -DOPUS_ARM_INLINE_MEDIA \
                -DOPUS_ARM_INLINE_ASM -DOPUS_ARM_INLINE_EDSP -DOPUS_ARM_INLINE_NEON \
                -DOPUS_ARM_MAY_HAVE_EDSP -DOPUS_ARM_MAY_HAVE_MEDIA -DOPUS_ARM_MAY_HAVE_NEON \
                -DOPUS_ARM_PRESUME_EDSP -DOPUS_ARM_PRESUME_MEDIA \
                -DOPUS_ARM_MAY_HAVE_NEON_INTR -DOPUS_HAVE_RTCD
CPU_ARM=1
HAVE_ARM_NEON_INTR=1
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -msse4.2 -mavx
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPUS_X86_MAY_HAVE_SSE -DOPUS_X86_MAY_HAVE_SSE2 -DOPUS_X86_MAY_HAVE_SSE4_1 \
                -DOPUS_X86_MAY_HAVE_AVX -DOPUS_X86_PRESUME_SSE -DOPUS_X86_PRESUME_SSE2 \
                -DOPUS_HAVE_RTCD -DCPU_INFO_BY_C
HAVE_SSE=1
HAVE_SSE2=1
HAVE_SSE4_1=1
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mavx
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPUS_X86_MAY_HAVE_SSE -DOPUS_X86_MAY_HAVE_SSE2 -DOPUS_X86_MAY_HAVE_SSE4_1 \
                -DOPUS_X86_MAY_HAVE_AVX -DOPUS_X86_PRESUME_SSE -DOPUS_X86_PRESUME_SSE2 \
                -DOPUS_X86_PRESUME_SSE4_1 -DOPUS_HAVE_RTCD -DCPU_INFO_BY_C
HAVE_SSE=1
HAVE_SSE2=1
HAVE_SSE4_1=1
endif

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/silk_sources.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/celt_sources.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/opus_sources.mk

ifdef FIXED_POINT
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_FIXED)
ifdef HAVE_SSE4_1
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_SSE4_1) $(SILK_SOURCES_FIXED_SSE4_1)
endif
ifdef HAVE_ARM_NEON_INTR
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_FIXED_ARM_NEON_INTR)
endif
else
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_FLOAT)
ifdef HAVE_SSE4_1
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_SSE4_1)
endif
endif

ifdef FIXED_POINT
else
OPUS_SOURCES += $(OPUS_SOURCES_FLOAT)
endif

ifdef HAVE_SSE
CELT_SOURCES += $(CELT_SOURCES_SSE)
endif
ifdef HAVE_SSE2
CELT_SOURCES += $(CELT_SOURCES_SSE2)
endif
ifdef HAVE_SSE4_1
CELT_SOURCES += $(CELT_SOURCES_SSE4_1)
endif

ifdef CPU_ARM
CELT_SOURCES += $(CELT_SOURCES_ARM)
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_ARM)

ifdef HAVE_ARM_NEON_INTR
CELT_SOURCES += $(CELT_SOURCES_ARM_NEON_INTR)
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_ARM_NEON_INTR)
endif

ifdef HAVE_ARM_NE10
CELT_SOURCES += $(CELT_SOURCES_ARM_NE10)
endif
endif

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(patsubst %,$(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/%,$(SILK_SOURCES) $(CELT_SOURCES) $(OPUS_SOURCES)) \
    com_score_rahasak_utils_OpusEncoder.c \
    com_score_rahasak_utils_OpusDecoder.c

all:
    echo $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/include/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/silk/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/silk/fixed \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/silk/float \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/celt/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/src/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/

ifdef FIXED_POINT
CFLAGS += -DFIXED_POINT=1 -DDISABLE_FLOAT_API
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/silk/fixed
else
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus/silk/float
endif

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures

# TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

Attach a link for opus wrapper:
[Opuslib wrapper](https://github.com/martoreto/opuscodec)

Hope for your help

In few moments after asking this question I found solution for Error 87.
You should add

```
LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true //(Android.mk)
APP_SHORT_COMMANDS := true //(Application.mk)
```

But after that I have another building error(Error 1):

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\DOROSHKO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsenz.so}
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : senz <= CNG.c
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
make: *** [D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/senz/D_/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/src/main/jni/opus/silk/code_signs.o.cflags.tmp] Error 1
```

after changing the gradle line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

this line disappeared

> [armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb : senz <= CNG.c

but Error 1 remained.

Build log:

```
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\DOROSHKO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsenz.so}
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
make: *** [D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/senz/D_/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/src/main/jni/opus/silk/code_signs.o.cflags.tmp] Error 1

    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\DOROSHKO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\GitProject\aliservicescontroller\AliServicesControllerAndroid\opuslib\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsenz.so}
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
make: *** [D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/senz/D_/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/src/main/jni/opus/silk/code_signs.o.cflags.tmp] Error 1

    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTaskUtils.executeBuildProcessAndLogError(ExternalNativeBuildTaskUtils.java:244)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTask.executeProcessBatch(ExternalNativeBuildTask.java:307)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTask.build(ExternalNativeBuildTask.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    ... 44 more
```

Hope for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo 'D:/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/senz/D_/GitProject/aliservicescontroller/AliServicesControllerAndroid/opuslib/src/main/jni/opus/silk/code_signs.o.cflags.tmp' | wc -c
266
```

This path is too long for Windows ([Windows file paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file) are limited to 260 characters). You'll need to move the project to be rooted in a shorter path.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I changed the path to the project. It works.